# I need this Substring counting program to return a Tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have come up with this piece of code to count multiple substrings within a string.  I need for it to return the results in a tuple.  Any Suggestions?

```
def FindSubstringMatch(target, key):
    PositionList = 0
    while PositionList < len(target):
        PositionList = target.find(key, PositionList)
        if PositionList == -1:
            break
        print(PositionList)
        PositionList += 2

FindSubstringMatch("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat", "atgc")
```

This piece of code prints:
5
15

I would like for it to return:
(5,15)

Comment: I encourage you to have a look at PEP 8 and to follow python naming conventions.

Comment: I think this part is wrong: `PositionList += 2` why are you jumping two chars at the time? it'll make your function fail for certain inputs, for example: `findSubstringMatch("attx", "t")` will return `(1,)`, but the correct answer is `(1, 2)`. I fixed this problem in my second answer

Comment: I'd like to point out that as you have presented your function, it currently has no `return` statement, so it python assumes you mean to write `return None` at the end.  To return something useful, you need to include a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def FindSubstringMatch(target, key):
    PositionList = 0
    result = []
    while PositionList < len(target):
        PositionList = target.find(key, PositionList)
        if PositionList == -1:
            break
        result.append(PositionList)
        PositionList += 2
    return tuple(result)
```

Even better, you can simplify the whole function like this:

```
from re import finditer

def findSubstringMatch(target, key):
    return tuple(m.start() for m in finditer(key, target))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
findSubstringMatch("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat", "atgc")
=> (5, 15)
```